# Apache Axis 1.x xml payload

Tags: java, xml, apache-axis

I'm using apache axis to consume a few SOAP operations. The web service I'm talking to takes XML as one of the payload inputs. I noticed that Axis is encoding the non xml friendly characters. IE `< >` to `&alt;` etc.. etc..

How can I tell apache Axis to allow my payload to go over un-encoded?

Comment: How exactly do you send your payload? Through a generated client or DII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this problem and the only way that I was able to solve it was by overriding the XMLEncoder which ships with Apache Axis 1.4.

I used [Jad](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to decompile the `com.org.apache.axis.components.encoding.UTF8Encoder`, copied the code into my own class and commented out the `&`, `"`, `<` and  `>` case statements.

To configure Axis to use this new Encoder you also have to create a

`META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoder`

file containing just the FQDN of your new class.